# Depend on module in multi-module Maven project when module doesn't produce an artifact

Tags: maven

I have a multi-module maven project that contains the following modules:

1. `system-x-server`
2. `system-x-client`
3. `system-x-server-image`
4. `system-x-integration-tests`

The `system-x-server-image` produces a docker image that is used to conduct integration tests within the tests-only `system-x-integration-tests` project. Adding it as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>system-x-server-image</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Produces an error because the `system-x-server-image` doesn't produce an artifact (it does, but not one that's resolved using Maven).

Is there some way that I can make the the `system-x-integration-tests` depend on the `system-x-server-image` given that `system-x-server-image` doesn't produce an artifact?

Comment: How does your pom files look like?

Answer (score 0):

Please set `packaging` to `pom` in `system-x-server-image` module.

```
<project ...>
 ...
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
 ...
```